# Laravel replace abbreviations by words in blade

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-blade

We have specific columns in tables having a status, these are abbreviations, we want these short words beeing replaced by full words.

for example:

```
E => Error
R => Running
D => Done
```

I already seen things as Laravel Translation, but this is not what we need I suppose? This is not a language translation.

Looking for something where I can set the full words of each abbreviation, and show these full words in blade like:

```
@get_full_word(column_name)
```

which will output the full name

Comment: I am hoping that just like abbrevations, you also store full forms in your table. Pull those.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a best case for Mutators.

```
class Test extends Model
{

    protected $fullStatus = [
        'E' => 'Error',
        'R' => 'Running',
        'D' => 'Done',
    ];


    public function getFullStatusAttribute()
    {
        return $this->fullStatus[
            $this->status
        ];
    }
}
```

And of course if its in many Classes, it would be nice to create a Trait that holds the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#extending-blade).

```
Blade::directive('abbreviation', function ($abbreviation) {
    return "<?php echo Abbreviation::get($abbreviation); ?>";
});
```

where `Abbreviation` is your class with abbreviations, like this

```
class Abbreviation
{
    private $abbreviations = [
        'E' => 'Error'
        'R' => 'Running'
        'D' => 'Done'
    ];

    public static function get($abbreviation)
    {
        return $abbreviations[$abbreviation];
    }
}
```

Than you can use it in your blade `@abbreviation('D')`